# STM32F4 USART1 doesn't work correctly and return garbage data

Tags: stm32, uart, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4, usart

I am trying to work with STM32F407 USART1 peripheral but it doesn't work correctly. I have read the datasheet for many times but i couldn't find any solution.

I use FTDI232 for the communication. My connections are correct, i use this connection on MSP430. In the code, i don't use DMA for now because i don't know how to configure DMA currently (for multiple communication).

```
FTDI232 RX Pin ---> PA9 (STM32407 USART1 TX)
FTDI232 TX Pin ---> PA10 (STM32407 USART1 RX)
FTDI232 Ground ---> STM32F407 Ground
```

I have added comments for almost all lines.
Where is my mistake? Could you help me?

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"                  // Device header
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"              // Keil::Device:STM32Cube HAL:Common

/************************************************************ 
    CPU  Frequency  168Mhz
    AHB  Frequency  168MHz
    APB1 Frequency  42MHz
    APB2 Frequency  84MHz
************************************************************/

/************************* PLL Parameters *************************************/
/* PLL_VCO = (HSE_VALUE or HSI_VALUE / PLL_M) * PLL_N */
#define PLL_M      8
#define PLL_N      336

/* SYSCLK = PLL_VCO / PLL_P */
#define PLL_P      2

/* USB OTG FS, SDIO and RNG Clock =  PLL_VCO / PLLQ */
#define PLL_Q      7

/******************************************************************************/

#define CPU_PLL_CLK             168000000UL         // 168 MHz
#define AHB_BUS_CLK             168000000UL         // 168 MHz
#define APB1_BUS_CLK            42000000UL          // 42  MHz
#define APB2_BUS_CLK            84000000UL          // 84  MHz

// USART1 Functions
void            USART1_Init(uint32_t baudrate);
void            USART1_WriteChar(uint8_t data);

// Delay with MS
// Every Cycle = 5.95 ns (for 168 MHz)
void delay_ms(uint32_t delay_time)
{   
    delay_time *= (CPU_PLL_CLK / 1000) / 5.95;
    while(delay_time--);
}

/* PLL_VCO = (HSE_VALUE or HSI_VALUE / PLL_M) * PLL_N
     SYSCLK = PLL_VCO / PLL_P
*/ 
void System_Config(void)
{

    RCC->CFGR        = 0x00000000;                  // CFGR All Cleared - System Clock HSI
    RCC->CFGR           |=  (4    << 10);           // PPRE1 - APB1 - AHB clock divided by 2
    RCC->CFGR           |=  (4    << 13);           // PPRE2 - APB2 - AHB clock divided by 2
    RCC->CR             |=  (1    << 16);           // HSEON - HSE External Oscillator

    while (!(RCC->CR & 0x00020000));        // HSERDY - Wait HSE active

    RCC->PLLCFGR    |=  (8      <<  0);         // PLLM = 8;
    RCC->PLLCFGR    |=  (336    <<  6);         // PLLN = 336;
    RCC->PLLCFGR    &= ~(3    << 16);           // PLLP = 2;    For 2, write 00
    RCC->PLLCFGR    |=  (7      << 24);         // PLLQ = 7;

    RCC->CR             |=  (1    << 24);           // PLLON - PLL Active

    while (!(RCC->CR & 0x02000000));        // PLLRDY - Wait PLL active

    FLASH->ACR      |=  (5    <<  0);           // Wait State = 5
    FLASH->ACR      |=  (1    <<  9);           // Data Cache active
    FLASH->ACR      |=  (1    << 10);           // Instruction Cache active

    RCC->CFGR       |=  (2    <<  0);     // System Clock PLL

    while ((RCC->CFGR & 0x0000000F) != 0x0000000A); // Wait until load

}

int main(void)
{

    System_Config();
    USART1_Init(115200);        // Parameter Not Used Now

    while(1)
    {
        USART1_WriteChar('a');
        delay_ms(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
    Tx/Rx baud = fCLK / (8 * (2 - OVER8) * USARTDIV)
                                OVER8 -> CR1 Register 15. Bit (Over Sampling)
                                fCLK = SystemClock
    8000000 / (16 * 9600)
*/
void USART1_Init(uint32_t baudrate)
{

    /* GPIOA clock enable */
    RCC->AHB1ENR        |= (1UL << 0);                                              //  RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;

    // AFR[0] = AFRL Register   - Address 0x20
    // AFR[1] = AFRH Register   - Address   0x21
    // GPIOA->AFR[1] |= (0x00000110);   

    GPIOA->MODER    |=  (2UL << 18);                                                // GPIO_AFRH_AFRH0 - PA9  - Alternate State 
    GPIOA->MODER    |=  (2UL << 20);                                                // GPIO_AFRH_AFRH1 - PA10 - Alternate State

    GPIOA->PUPDR &= ~((3 << 18) | (3 << 20));                               // No Pull UP/DOWN
    GPIOA->PUPDR |=   (1 << 18) | (1 << 20);                                // Pull UP

    GPIOA->AFR[1]   &= ~(15UL << 4);                                                // Clear AF Mode
    GPIOA->AFR[1]   &= ~(15UL << 8);                                                // Clear AF Mode
    GPIOA->AFR[1]   |=  (7UL << 4);                                                 // GPIO_AFRH_AFRH0 - PA9
    GPIOA->AFR[1]   |=  (7UL << 8);                                                 // GPIO_AFRH_AFRH1 - PA10

    // USART1 clock enable
    RCC->APB2ENR        |= (1UL << 4);                                                  // Enable USART1 - RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN;
    //RCC->APB2RSTR     |= (1UL << 4);  
    //RCC->APB2RSTR     &= ~(1UL << 4);                                             // USART1 Disable Reset Mode    

    USART1->CR2 &= ~(3 << 12);      // USART_STOPBITS_1

    USART1->CR1 &= ~(1 << 12);      //  USART_WORDLENGTH_8B
    USART1->CR1 &= ~(1 << 10);      //  USART_PARITY_NONE
    USART1->CR1 |=  (1 <<  7);      //  USART_CR1_TXEIE
    USART1->CR1 |=  (1 <<  5);      //  USART_CR1_RXNEIE
    USART1->CR1 |=  (1 <<  3);      //  USART_MODE_TX
    USART1->CR1 |=  (1 <<  2);      //  USART_MODE_RX

    //USART1->BRR     = SystemCoreClock / (16 * 115200);            // 115200 baud
    //USART1->BRR  = 84000000 / (16 * 115200);
    USART1->BRR  = 0x2D9;                     // 115200

    /* Enable the USART */
    USART1->CR1 |=  (1 <<  13);     //  USART_CR1_UE

    NVIC->ISER[1] = 1 << (USART1_IRQn - 32);        // USART1 Global Interrupt Enable
    //NVIC->ISER[1]  |= 0x20;                           // USART1 Interrupt Enable      

    //USART1->SR &= ~(0x40);                          // Status Register

}

void USART1_WriteChar(uint8_t data)
{
    while(!(USART1->SR & 0x80));      // USART_SR_TXE - USART_FLAG_TXE
    USART1->DR = data;  
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Are you running a serial monitor program on your PC? Are you using an oscilloscope? And what do you see?

Comment: I want to send char from STM to serial monitor on my PC with FTDI232. I don't use oscilloscope. I haven't see anything on my serial monitor.

Comment: Have you checked if your serial monitor works? You can do this by connecting the FTDI232's `TX` and `RX` lines. Then send a char through the FTDI, and you should receive it back.

Comment: Yes, i checked. My FTDI is working. I tried with MSP430, it is work but not work with STM32

Comment: where is your interrupt file? where you are handling receive interrupt?

Comment: Magic numbers are not good. Respect our time. Use human readable CMSIS definitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might also be due to a problem, that has nothing to do with your program. If you use the Discovery board with USART1, please note that some required pins (PA9 / PA10) are already in use.

Some further information [here](http://www.micromouseonline.com/2013/05/05/using-usart1-on-the-stm32f4discovery/).

Comment: Yes, my problem is PA9/PA10 pins for Discovery Board. This pins are used with USB. For this reason, if you want to use USART1, you must choose PB6/PB7 for Discovery Board. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you tried the solutions that @elasticman point out and again you get a bunch of garbage data, that's good to check following recommendation too. It's borrowed from [this](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/stm32f4discovery-usart-problems/) link.

> - (**) HSE_VALUE is a constant defined in stm32f4xx.h file
>     (default value 25 MHz), user has to ensure that HSE_VALUE is same as
>     the real frequency of the crystal used. Otherwise,
>     this function may have wrong result.

The crystal has been used in STM32F407 discovery board is 8MHz so it is important to correct the HSE_VALUE in the stm32f4xx.h file (by default is 25MHz) to 8MHz to ensure that USART will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change AHB clock as 64 MHz and then add further pre scalar to bring APB1 under 42MHz I don't know the reason but over 64MHz it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a fix. If you pull up your gpio pin

```
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
```

you could get USART1 (which is connected to the st-link in my board) to work, regardless of the peripheral overload implemented by ST.

(edit): I see that you already set the PUPDR to pullup, sorry if doesn't solve this problem, but it did solve mine. I'm working with a STM32F429Disc1 board by the way.